# Is it possible to whitelist upstream packages in azure devops without disabling upstream sources?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a business need to manually approve every (external) upstream change before we start using it and only allow our developers to use an approved whitelist of packages and versions.

The two ways I can see to do this are either:

1. disable all pipelines and halt all development, enable an upstream source and pull the new package through and then disable it; making sure no additional upstream packages were pulled while the source was enabled
2. not use upstream sources but instead republish all packages manually (ongoing work will not be impacted while package approvals occur)

I have some basic tooling created to manage the manual approval and republish pipeline (I currently do this with a network local nuget registry and npm registry) so #2 seems like the path for me to take, but if I could simply upload a list of approved packages instead I could maybe simplify my workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to whitelist upstream packages in azure devops without disabling upstream sources?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such way to whitelist upstream packages without disabling upstream sources at this moment.

Just as you know, there is not much settings for upstream sources currently, just add/delete, enable/disable. We could not have any way to set a whitelist to filter the packets from the upstream source.

As you have a business need to manually approve every (external) upstream change, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Besides, as workaround, I also agree with the second way. We could use [file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) to publish multiple packages:

[Push NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops#push-nuget-packages)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have requested a feature here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/726460/upstream-source-package-whitelisting.html