# Azure DevOps Restrict Packages Allowed in Artifact Feed From Upstream Sources

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, nuget

In Azure DevOps Artifacts, is there a way to restrict the packages that are used in a feed from an upstream source?

For instance, we have a private feed with some custom built nuget packages. There are also some packages from nuget.org that we would still like to use, so we have that configured as an upstream source. However, we would only like to allow a subset of 'approved' nuget packages from nuget.org to maintain consistency over our code base. Is there a way to limit the upstream source to a list of 'approved' packages like this or is that not possible and all packages are allowed when using an upstream source?

Comment: Please refer [Upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) , [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811246/is-it-possible-to-whitelist-upstream-packages-in-azure-devops-without-disabling) and [Upstream source package whitelisting](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/upstream-source-package-whitelisting/726460)

Comment: Feed Views restrict users from consuming non-production-ready versions of a package from an upstream source. Have a look at [Feed views](https://decovar.dev/blog/2021/07/21/azure-devops-artifacts-promotion/)